# WPF - Define a alias for a SolidColorBrush In App.Resource (StaticResourceExtension?)

Tags: wpf, xaml, alias

I use MaterialDesign in my app and I would like to give an alias to the `PrimaryHueLightBrush` SolidColorBursh, which is defined there. I have found that **StaticResourceExtension** seems to be the solution to this. But I have not been able to get this to work.
Also I would like the "alias" to be defined in the App.xaml so the alias will be accessible from my entire application.

I have defined the "alias" in the **App.xaml** and I use it in the **MainWindow.xaml**.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="MaterialDesignTest.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignTest"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <StaticResourceExtension x:Key="MyAlias" ResourceKey="PrimaryHueLightBrush" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="MaterialDesignTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignTest"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="500">

    <Border Background="{DynamicResource MyAlias}" />
</Window
```

In the designer of my MainWindow I can see that the Border gets the `DeepPurple` color defined in the App.xaml file. So that connection seem to work.

When I try to run my application there is an error:
`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

VS point the error to the beginning of the `x:Key` parameter of the StaticResourceExtension element in the App.xaml-file.

Is there a solution for this?
I don't need to use a StaticResourceExtension. Just something so I can have an alias.

Answer (score 1):

`PrimaryHueLightBrush` is the "alias".

What you can do is to create a copy of the brush and reference the copy instead:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyAlias" Color="{Binding Color,
    Source={StaticResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}}"/>
```